# How to enter text in javascript div-style input box with casperjs

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

A website I'm accessing utilizes a javascript code editor (code mirror) attached to a textarea box. This results in a div-style input box. How do I use casperjs to enter text into the box?

I've already tried entering text into the hidden textarea using sendkeys and it doesn't find the selector (because it is hidden).

Update:

```
this.evaluate(function(input) {
    window.$('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror.setValue(input);
}, intent_schema);
```

enters the text into the box as expected, but when I submit the form, the values aren't saved. Something isn't firing properly.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try the evaluate function and then use the querySelector of the dom element. Then you can adjust the dom element from there. `casper.evaluate(function() { var te = document.querySelector("path to hidden selector"); // Now you can do something with te });`

Comment: that gets you the selector. What do you do with it to enter text?

Comment: The problem you are facing could come from any variety of conditions. This question cannot be answered with certainty without knowing the website you are trying to access and its underlying functionality regarding the form submission.